# insertion in a binary tree ( not BST ) not working

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

In the following code I have written a insertion function for a binary tree. But after each call it doesn't inserting any node to the tree. I have checked the algorithm for insertion in a binary tree. I think there is some pointer issue but can't figure it out why this is happening. Is there any restriction for a function on changing the pointer or assigning it with another pointer in c++?

```
//binary tree implementation

#include<iostream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

//node class with a constructor 
struct NODE {
    int data;
    NODE *lc,*rc;

    NODE() {
        lc=rc=NULL;
    }
};
```

---

```
//tree class with a constructor
struct TREE {
    NODE *root;

    TREE() {
        root = NULL;
    } 
};
```

---

```
//insertion in a binary tree
//uses queue to keep track of nodes level wise   

void insertNode(NODE *r, int key) {
    NODE *newNode = new NODE;    //getting a new node
    newNode->data = key;         //setting the value of the node to key

    if(!r) {                     //if r is NULL
        //then this is where the new node to be inserted
        r = newNode;
        return;
    }

    queue<NODE*> q;              //Creating a queue of NODE* to store the
    q.push(r);                   //node at each level ,push r to the queue.
    while(!q.empty()) {          //Using a level order traversal
                                //to insert a node to the binary tree.  
        NODE *temp = q.front();  //And inserting the element wherever we
        q.pop();                 //found the node whose left or right child
        if(temp->lc)             //is NULL 
            q.push(temp->lc);    ///If temp has a left child then push it 
        else {                   ///into the queue
                                 ///else insert the node here
            temp->lc = newNode;
            return;
        }
        if(temp->rc)             ///If temp has a right child the push it
            q.push(temp->rc);    ///into the queue
        else {                   ///else insert the node here
             temp->rc = newNode;
             return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//inorder traversal of the tree
void inorder(NODE *r) {
    if(r) {
        inorder(r->lc);
        cout<<r->data<<" ";
        inorder(r->rc);
    }
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    TREE t;
    insertNode(t.root,5);           //inserting 5 to the tree t
    insertNode(t.root,10);          //inserting 10 to the tree t
    insertNode(t.root,15);          //inserting 15 to the tree t

    inorder(t.root);     `          //Now traversing the tree.
                                    ///**But after each insertion root of 
                                    ///tree t is still empty.
                                    ///it means the pointer is not being 
                                    ///changed by the insertionNode fn 
                                    ///but cant figure this out

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's really odd that you're defining procedural methods that operate on `struct`s rather than a `class` with methods built-in. Where does the `insertNode` function insert the node, anyway?

Comment: Here's the thing. If `r` is null (has `0x00`), it will enter the if, assign an address to `r`, and return. The problem is that `r` is a pointer to `0x00`.. inside `insertNode`, `r` will have the new address. However, after leaving the method scope, `r` will still be `0x00` because the function is not passing `r` as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of your code:

```
void insertNode(NODE *r, int key)
{
   r = newNode;             //inserted
   return;
}
```

Your parameter is a *copy* of the pointer you've passed. The assignment changes that copy, but not the argument to the function. The copy then gets immediately destroyed by the `return`.

Change the argument to a reference to fix that:

```
void insertNode(NODE *&r, int key)
{
   r = newNode;             //inserted
   return;
}
```

Even better, since your function is only ever called on the root node pointer of a `TREE`, pass that `TREE` by reference.

And even better, since tree insertion belongs to the tree, make the function a member function of `TREE`. Then the tree will be passed as implicit `this`, and you can simply access `root` directly. And you'll have a better interface, too.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is there any restriction for a function on changing the pointer or assigning it with another pointer in c++?
>   "*

Yes there is a restriction regarding scope of the function parameters (that well applies for c function parameters too). When you call this code

```
insertNode(t.root,5);
```

`t.root` equals `NULL`, and the assignment to the newly allocated `NODE` is performed correctly. But you are changing a local copy of the pointer calling `insertNode()`, since the pointer parameter `r` is passed by value

```
void insertNode(NODE *r, int key) {
    NODE *newNode = new NODE;    //getting a new node
    newNode->data = key;         //setting the value of the node to key

    if(!r)  {  
        r = newNode;  // <<<<<<<
        return;
    }
    // ...
```

and that newly created node is never written back to `t.root`.

Change your function signature to take a reference to that pointer

```
    void insertNode(NODE*& r, int key) {
                      // ^
```

thus it will actually change the variable passed to that function. This will fix the primary problem.

---

Though I have to agree with [@tadman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201304/insertion-in-a-binary-tree-not-bst-not-working/30201474#comment48508335_30201304) it's really odd to have free functions for `insertNode()` or `inorder()`. These should be non static class member functions of `TREE` actually.